# How to fire google floodlight tag on gravity form submission?

Tags: jquery, gravityforms, google-floodlight

I tried the following and is not working :-

```
$(document).bind('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(){
    var axel = Math.random() + "";
    var a = axel * 10000000000000;
    $('body').append('<script type="text/javascript"><iframe src="https://4086067.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=4086067;type=marke675;cat=busin00a;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=1;num=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe></script>');
    $('body').append('<noscript><iframe src="https://4086067.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=4086067;type=marke675;cat=busin00a;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=1;num=1?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe></noscript>');
});
```